# X509Certificate2.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider returns null in .Net Standards 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, .net-standard, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I am writing a .Net Standard 2.1 class library that implements some cryptographic logic. I need to create a RSACryptoServiceProvider object from .pfx file to create a signature for my OpenIdConnect provider. I use the following code to do that.

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(filePath, password, 
X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var privateKey = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsaProvider.FromXmlString(privateKey .ToXmlString(true));
var rsaFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsaProvider);
rsaFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
var sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
var hashSignatureBytes 
=rsaFormatter.CreateSignature(sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)));
hashSignatureBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(hashSignatureBytes);
return hashSignatureBase64;
```

This code is working in .Net 4.7 perfectly. But it does not work in .Net Standards 2.1 the reason is

```
var privateKey = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
```

returns null

Does anyone know how to resolve this in .Net Standards? Thanks in advance

Comment: What version is your target?  Net Standard 2.1 can target Core 3.0, Core 3.1, Core 5.0, Core 6.0.  Try target Core 5.0 or 6.0.  Cyptography doesn't always work with Core 3.0 (and maybe 3.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem is that the type of `certificate.PrivateKey` depends on the environment and is not necessarily `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, so the cast fails and `as` returns `null`.

Example: `certificate.PrivateKey` is of type `RSACryptoServiceProvider` on .NET Framework 4.7.2 (.NET Standard 2.0), of type `RSACng` on .NET Core 3.0 or .NET 6.0 (.NET Standard 2.1) on Windows (10) and of type `RSAOpenSsl` on Linux/Ubuntu (for an overview of .NET Standard versions see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-1)).

To fix the issue, use [`GetRSAPrivateKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.getrsaprivatekey?view=net-6.0) instead, which is supported in .NET Standard 2.0 and 2.1. This returns an RSA implementation supported by the respective environment (with [`RSA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa?view=net-6.0) as base class), which can be passed directly to the formatter class:

```cs
var privateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
var rsaFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(privateKey);
```

Note that [`PrivateKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey?view=net-6.0) should be avoided because it is deprecated.

---

Apart from that, signing is more convenient with [`RSA#SignData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.signdata?view=net-6.0) (though this is a matter of opinion):

```cs
byte[] hashSignatureBytes = privateKey.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
```

Comment: Import/Sign on .NET6 (.NET Standard 2.1) can be run online on Linux/Ubuntu here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lBCB15

Comment: thank you for your answer. But in my case certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey(); also didnt work for me.  Then I came up with the following solution and it works fine in Windows 10. Please do let me if there are any consequences of this

Comment: @Rama - It's already explained in my answer: On Windows platforms and under .NET Standard 2.1, `certificate.PrivateKey` corresponds to an `RSACng` instance. Thus, if these requirements are always met, you can use `certificate.PrivateKey as RSACng` instead of `certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey()`. It is just not a *general* solution and uses a *deprecated* functionality, so it is not recommendable. Why `certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey()` (after all the way intended by MS) doesn't work in your environment I don't understand (but your comment *also didnt work for me* isn't very meaningful either).